# Set a variable and pass it thru

Tags: powershell

The following works but is ugly.

```
> Get-CimInstance win32_process | `
    select -first 5
    foreach { $process = $_; $process; } |     # this is ugly
    foreach { write $process.ProcessName }

System Idle Process
System
smss.exe
csrss.exe
wininit.exe
```

We've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
> Get-CimInstance win32_process | 
    select -first 5
    foreach { Set-Variable $c -PassThru } |    # this is prettier
    foreach { write $c.ProcessName }

wininit.exe
wininit.exe
wininit.exe
wininit.exe
wininit.exe
```

How can we make `Set-Variable` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting a value for the variable in your set-variable call, and the name shouldn't have a $ symbol

```
PS C:\> 1,2,3 | ForEach { Set-Variable -Name c -Value $_ -PassThru } | ForEach { "-$c-" }
-1-
-2-
-3-
```

Although I don't know how/if the variable value carries in sync with the pipeline or if it can get out of sync. What about

```
$names = foreach ($c in Get-CimInstance win32_process | Select -First 5) {
    write $c.ProcessName
}
```

Here it is using your example of `CimInstance`.

```
PS C:\> Get-CimInstance win32_process | `
    select -first 5 | ` 
    foreach { Set-Variable -name process -value $_ -PassThru } | ` 
    foreach { write $process.ProcessName }

System Idle Process
System
smss.exe
csrss.exe
wininit.exe
```